# MySQL: Convert Field with StackOverflow-style Coded URLs to HTML

Tags: mysql, regex, regexp-replace

We have a legacy database table full of StackOverflow-like coded URLs.

```
=====================================================================================
| TABLE_COMMENTS                                                                    |
=====================================================================================
| f_ID | f_comment                                                                 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1  | To buy coffee [click here](https://google.com) or [here](https://bing.com) |
|   2  | Check [this out](https://stackoverflow.com)                                |
|   3  | [Cat Photos](https://google.com/images/?cats)                              |
=====================================================================================
```

I need to SELECT these as standard HTML so they look like the below table.

```
| f_comment                                                                                        |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| To buy coffee <a href="https://google.com">click here</a> or <a href="https://bing.com">here</a> |
| Check <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">this out</a>                                           |
| <a href="https://google.com/images/?cats">Cat Photos</a>                                         |
====================================================================================================
```

I have a method that will work if there is just one URL in the `f_comment` field, but I can't work out how to make it work for, like `row 1` where there are two URLs.

```sql
SELECT 
    CONCAT(
        substring_index(substring_index(f_comment, '[', 1),')', 1),
        "<a href=", 
        substring_index(substring_index(f_comment, '(', -1),')', 1),
        ">",
        substring_index(substring_index(f_comment, '[', -1),']', 1),
        "</a>"
    )
    AS f_replacementtext
FROM TABLE_COMMENTS;
```

[SQL Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wFAMRUk8HmqYBCEV7JpGWn/8)

Results of my **incomplete** query, where it misses the first URL of `f_ID` 1

```
 ==========================================================
| f_comment                                                |
 ----------------------------------------------------------
| To buy coffee <a href="https://bing.com">here</a>        |
| Check <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">this out</a>   |
| <a href="https://google.com/images/?cats">Cat Photos</a> |
 ==========================================================
```

Comment: `Select regexp_replace(f_comment, '\[([^]]+)\]\(([^\)]+)\)', '<a href="$2">$1</a>')`.  Default is to replace all occurrences.  Hard to parse the regular expression but it finds square brackets

Comment: ...followed by round brackets and rearranges what's inside them.

Comment: What version of MySQL?  (Some things are better done in application code than in SQL.)

Comment: @RickJames MySQL 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set @col =
'To buy coffee <a src=https://google.com>click here</a> or <a src=https://bing.com>here</a>';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( @col, '<a src=(http.*?)>(.*?)</a>', '[$2]($1)');
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| REGEXP_REPLACE( @col, '<a src=(http.*?)>(.*?)</a>', '[$2]($1)')            |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| To buy coffee [click here](https://google.com) or [here](https://bing.com) |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Going the other way...

```
SET @col =
'To buy coffee [click here](https://google.com) or [here](https://bing.com)';
SELECT
REGEXP_REPLACE( @col, '\\[(.*?)\\][(](http.*?)[)]',
                      '<a src=\$2>\$1</a>' ); 

+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| REGEXP_REPLACE( @col, '\\[(.*?)\\][(](http.*?)[)]',
                          '<a src=\$2>\$1</a>' ) |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| To buy coffee <a src=https://google.com>click here</a> or <a src=https://bing.com>here</a>           |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This seems to be the opposite of what I'm looking to do, but is definitely the right idea. I have the StackOverflow-style comment code, but need to convert to HTML.  I'll see if I can play with this to make it do the opposite, but I think my biggest problem will be when I try to move the HREF text after the URL.

Comment: @Beems - I started over, flipped them, showed how to use `$1` and tricky characters.

Comment: I appreciate the help - I 'kind of' see how the variables work, despite regex being a big bugaboo for me. This works great.